# How can i save this result in a variable?

Tags: linux, shell

I just want to store the result of this command in a variable but it does not work,

```
echo "${dir##*/}" | sed -r 's/[$  :@?!]+/_/g'
```

For the try.

```
fixfolderNamesTest.sh: line 76: syntax error near unexpected token `|'

line=(${dir##*/} | sed -r 's/[$  :@?!]+/_/g')
echo "$line"
```

Comment: Does `line=$(${dir##*/} | sed -r 's/[$  :@?!]+/_/g')` work? This uses `var=$(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your problem further even the below will provide the same error:

```
$ ls
a.csv  cr  f1  f2  file  s  t
$ ls | grep file
file
$ echo $out

$ out=(ls | grep file)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
$ echo $out

$ out=`ls | grep file`
$ echo $out
file
```

I would suggest using backticks to capture the output into a variable.

Comment: `out=$()` would be proper form. You missed the dollar sign